# textbox not showing up in gridview in templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my textbox is not showing up in my gridview, whats my error in my code? did i miss something? i dont know if i need to put a cssclas into it. the reason why the other templatefields has bind in it, it is because i get the data from the database, and i wanted to add a textbox to the gridview to update a certain field.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvModal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" EmptyDataText="No Records" AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-hover" >
        <Columns>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ID" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Type" HeaderStyle-Width="230px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemType") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Model" HeaderStyle-Width="210px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemModel") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Requested Quantity" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuan" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="AMS Balance" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAMS" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>     
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Unit" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUnit" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemUnit") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Date Needed" HeaderStyle-Width="180px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"  Text='<%#Bind ("ItemDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Description" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Status" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Remarks" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#336699" ItemStyle-Width="170px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>                  
            </asp:TemplateField>       
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Issuance" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#336699" ItemStyle-Width="170px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblIssued" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                  
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#336699" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>    
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#336699" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblUnits" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                        
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all CSS and set Visible to true.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Please also provide a screenshot and your code behind, so people can help you better.